# Test Plan with ApacheBench(AB) testing tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load-testing, apachebench, locust

I am trying load testing here. My backend is in Ruby(2.2) on Rails(3).
I read many pages about how to work with Ab testing.

Here is what I have tried:
**ab -n 100 -c 30 url**

Result:

```
    This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1554214 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 52.74.130.35 (be patient).....done


Server Software:        nginx/1.6.2
Server Hostname:        52.74.130.35
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          url
Document Length:        1372 bytes

Concurrency Level:      3
Time taken for tests:   10.032 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      181600 bytes
HTML transferred:       137200 bytes
Requests per second:    9.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       300.963 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       100.321 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          17.68 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2    9  25.0      5     227
Processing:   176  289 136.5    257    1134
Waiting:      175  275  77.9    256     600
Total:        180  298 139.2    264    1143

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    264
  66%    285
  75%    293
  80%    312
  90%    361
  95%    587
  98%   1043
  99%   1143
```

Which seams to be working perfectly. But my problem is I want to test many API's, not just one. So I have to write a script in which I write all the Api's with particular probabilities(weights) and load test on them.

I know how its possible with **Locust**, but locust does not support nested json to be passed as parameters.

Can somebody help with this.
Also let me know if there is any problem/ambiguity in the question itself.